# Database is locked while updating data in background

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I'm working on an application where I've to use sqlite and there are lots of data. I want to load data from "residents_status" column of a table named "tblResident". it is taking too much time to load data of that column (residents_status) more than 8 seconds and other data takes just a second. During the period of fetching the data from "residents_status" column, if I press a button its give me 'query error'
in else part but if I click button after 8 seconds than it is working fine.

**Here is my code:**

```
if(sqlite3_exec(database, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK)
{
  NSLog(@"succeddd.....");
    IsValidate = true;
    if([self checkNetConnection])
    {
        [self UpdateServerWith_LocalDB];
        NSString *Key= [DefaultsValues getStringValueFromUserDefaults_ForKey: @"Key"];

        if([[DefaultsValues getStringValueFromUserDefaults_ForKey: @"LastAuthenticationStatus"] isEqualToString:@"false"]){
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Your Access is Restrcited,Please contact us" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}
else{
    NSLog(@"query error");
    ErrorMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", error ];
    IsValidate = false;
}
```

Comment: 8 seconds for how many rows?  You're also doing some sort of network sync of the database too, by the look of it.  However you don't mention that in your question?!?